# How to conect Google Apps Script JDBC to Amazon RDS with SSL

Tags: ssl, google-apps-script, amazon-rds

Google launched support for SSL connections in the JDBC service. Google added three new connection parameters to support this feature: `_serverSslCertificate`, `_clientSslCertificate`, and `_clientSslKey`. The documentation is available here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getConnection(String,Object)

When a database in Amazon is created, we can add SSL support to it:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html

As an example if we create a MariaDB database, we just have to download the next certificate: `rds-ca-2015-root.pem`

And access to database with the next command:

```
mysql -h mymariadbinstance.abcd1234.rds-us-east-1.amazonaws.com --ssl-ca=[full path]rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert
```

And apply SSL to an specific user:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'encrypted_user'@'%' REQUIRE SSL
```

So, how can we conect with SSL to an Amazon Database using the GAS JDBC API?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't entirely clear to me, but it looks like you asking how you can pass the server cert while initiating the jdbc connection. The API has a `_serverSslCertificate` argument that should do just this.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getConnection(String,Object)

Try it out and let us know if you still have issues.